# How to use htaccess to rename pages and remove extensions without affecting css or js external files

Tags: regex, .htaccess, redirect, file-rename

I want to create a rule in htaccess to rename my pages, for example:

I want that domain.com/page1 actually opens the page domain.com/content?p=page1 or
domain.com/page2 actually opens the page domain.com/content?p=page2

for this I have a very simple regexp:

```
RewriteRule (.*)$ /content.php?p=$ [L]
```

now the problem is that this affects EVERYTHING even files like styles.css or functions.js, etc, or even images/logo.jpg.

So what I am looking for is for a regular expression that will forward all my pages if they do not have dots (.) or slashes (/)

for example:

```
domain.com/blog  true
domain.com/home?lang=en true
domain.com/styles.css false
domain.com/image.png false
domain.com/folder/file false
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

See the code below:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine on

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f

    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ content.php?p=$1 [L,QSA]
</IfModule>
```

If the requested URL isn't a directory and isn't a file, will be executed the next line.

Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

This is the code you need to put in your .htaccess file:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l
RewriteRule ^([^/.]+)/?$ content.php?p=$1 [L,QSA]
```

Comment: `!-l` is for avoiding the RewriteRule if Requested URI is a **valid link**.